# How to host an interactive python script on the web

Tags: python, web

Forgive my ignorance but (in the modern era) my skills are limited to python and Wordpress with some HTML and a little bit of CSS.

I would like to demonstrate a software as a service idea by hosting a python script (I've already written) on the web. I'd like advice on the Platform and the user interface. At this stage I just want something quick and functional.

After some initial input from the user (basically a few key words and some other details)  the Script searches the web and outputs a number of secondary keywords. I'd like the user to be able to choose which secondary keywords to take forward. Maybe drag and drop but could be just using arrow buttons to take a key word from one list/box to the next like in Microsoft Dynamics, for example. Flashy would be nice but not if it's going to slow me down and getting the thing up and running.

I'd really appreciate advice on how I could get the script up on the web. Apart from writing the Python script I've done nothing so I'm starting from a blank sheet of paper.

Comment: Sounds like you want to write a `CGI` script. Look at python's [cgi module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/cgi.html).

Comment: There are quite a few Python web frameworks - flask (light-weight) and django (batteries-included) come to mind.

Comment: jypiter? http://jupyter.org/